# Receiving error: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth

I installed Python Social Auth on my vm and tried to run `makemigrations` and receiving this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/opt/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py",
line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/opt/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 312,
in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/opt/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py",
line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/opt/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, 
in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/opt/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py",
line 127, in create
    "'%s' isn't a subclass of AppConfig." % entry)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'social.apps.django_app.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware'
isn't a subclass of AppConfig.
```

I ran the same application on my localhost and it's working fine. I cannot understand what this error says. Please help.

Comment: Did you include the path in your INSTALLED_APPS in your settings file?

Answer (score 17):

Seems you added `social.apps.django_app.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware` to `INSTALLED_APPS` in your *settings.py*.

You should add it to `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` instead.

Comment: whoopsies. Thanks for correcting my code with your mind.

Comment: I got the same error for 'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware', I put it i  intalled_apps instead that in middleware by mistake